# Can't pair my phone with my Windows 8 computer on a Cyanogenmod 13 install without Gapps

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, windows, bluetooth-pairing

Long story short, I managed to pair once, but I couldn't send files. I un-paired and can't re-pair to it.

The phone keeps saying "Failed to communicate, incorrect pin or passkey" and my computer says "Adding this device failed, please remove the device and try again" during the *pairing* process.

I have installed Cyanogenmod 13 over the Android 4.0.1 kernel it had before, but I haven't installed gapps on it yet. I've seen some other issues here and there, but they haven't really impacted much, but I'm worried it might have something to do with it.

Edit: I should mention that I want to send files both ways, forgot to in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are sending files from your android device to your PC.

Just download the **Xender app** from google play store and open that app.

I will provide you 2 solutions.

- Both PC and android device should be on same wifi network. In PC,
  open a browser and type web.xender.com. You can pair the device.

  In your android device, create a hotspot and connect the PC with it.
  Just proceed with respect to the instruction given by the xender app.

I had similar problem before and I have documented the same.

https://tjosepraveenblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/transfer-files-from-my-phone-to-pc-without-using-a-usb-cable-and-vice-versa/

Comment: I'm actually trying to send both ways, but this is also helpful, I'll add some more to the question for the future. Thanks for the link, I'll be using this for now at least.

Comment: It's my pleasure